# DBD::Pg compilation error (Windows 10 / Strawberry Perl)

Tags: perl, module, strawberry-perl, dbd

I'm trying to install the DBD::Pg (3.7.4) module on my windows 10/Strawberry Perl, but the compilation failed

For that I downloaded the module on metacpan and executed following command in the windows terminal:

```
perl Makefile.PL phrtsd_orig
```

Response:

```
Configuring DBD::Pg 3.7.4
PostgreSQL version: 90603 (default port: 5432)
POSTGRES_HOME: (not set)
POSTGRES_INCLUDE: C:/STRAWB~1/c/include
POSTGRES_LIB: C:/STRAWB~1/c/lib
OS: MSWin32
Multiple copies of Driver.xst found in: C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/auto/DBI/ C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/auto/DBI/ at Makefile.PL line 182.
Multiple copies of Driver.xst found in: C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/auto/DBI/ C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/auto/DBI/ at Makefile.PL line 285.
Using DBI 1.64 (for perl 5.026001 on MSWin32-x64-multi-thread) installed in C:/Strawberry/perl/site/lib/auto/DBI/
Generating a gmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for DBD::Pg
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
```

But the problem comes after the execution of the command `gmake`.
Response:

```
Skip blib\lib/Bundle/DBD/Pg.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib\lib\DBD/Pg.pm (unchanged)
Running Mkbootstrap for Pg ()
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Command -e chmod -- 644 "Pg.bs"
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e cp_nonempty -- Pg.bs blib\arch\auto\DBD\Pg\Pg.bs 644
gcc -c  -I"C:/STRAWB~1/c/include" -IC:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib\auto\DBI -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DCONSERVATIVE -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -DPGLIBVERSION=90603 -DPGDEFPORT=5432 -s -O2   -DVERSION=\"3.7.4\" -DXS_VERSION=\"3.7.4\"  "-IC:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE"   Pg.c
gcc -c  -I"C:/STRAWB~1/c/include" -IC:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib\auto\DBI -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DCONSERVATIVE -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -DPGLIBVERSION=90603 -DPGDEFPORT=5432 -s -O2   -DVERSION=\"3.7.4\" -DXS_VERSION=\"3.7.4\"  "-IC:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE"   dbdimp.c
gcc -c  -I"C:/STRAWB~1/c/include" -IC:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib\auto\DBI -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DCONSERVATIVE -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -DPGLIBVERSION=90603 -DPGDEFPORT=5432 -s -O2   -DVERSION=\"3.7.4\" -DXS_VERSION=\"3.7.4\"  "-IC:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE"   quote.c
gcc -c  -I"C:/STRAWB~1/c/include" -IC:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib\auto\DBI -s -O2 -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DCONSERVATIVE -D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO -DPERL_TEXTMODE_SCRIPTS -DPERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT -DPERL_IMPLICIT_SYS -DUSE_PERLIO -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -mms-bitfields -DPGLIBVERSION=90603 -DPGDEFPORT=5432 -s -O2   -DVERSION=\"3.7.4\" -DXS_VERSION=\"3.7.4\"  "-IC:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE"   types.c
g++ Pg.def -o blib\arch\auto\DBD\Pg\Pg.xs.dll -mdll -s -L"C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE" -L"C:\STRAWB~1\c\lib" Pg.o dbdimp.o quote.o types.o   "C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib\CORE\libperl526.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\lib\libpq.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libm.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libsecur32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libmoldname.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libkernel32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libuser32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libgdi32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libwinspool.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libcomdlg32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libadvapi32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libshell32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libole32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\liboleaut32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libnetapi32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libuuid.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libws2_32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libmpr.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libwinmm.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libversion.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libodbc32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libodbccp32.a" "C:\STRAWB~1\c\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib\libcomctl32.a" -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base
quote.o:quote.c:(.text+0x63d): undefined reference to `__imp__snprintf.constprop.4'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake: *** [Makefile:496: blib\arch\auto\DBD\Pg\Pg.xs.dll] Error 1
```

In case this information can help, I have two other module installed:

- Switch (2.17)
- DBI (1.640)

Thanks in advance for you help !

Comment: It looks that there is a bug on the version that you are trying to install, see here for more info (https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=122019). Try downloading the latest version 3.7.4 (http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-Pg/Pg.pm), the fix of the problem should be populated from 3.7.1 and onward.

Comment: @Thanos thanks for your help, but I was already installing the latest version. My problem has been solved by the patch given by daxim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce this with DBD-Pg-3.7.4. [It is a known bug.](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=122019) The [patch by kmx](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=122019#txn-1740155) worked for me.

Comment: According to the bug report the fix is in 3.7.1 the latest version is 3.7.4 so I think the best solution is to download 3.7.4 and install. Probably the OP is trying to install an older version of 3.7.1

Comment: We both – op and I – have DBD-Pg-3.7.4; you're wrong.

Comment: I am not wrong, it is mentioned in the bug report (Fixed in: 3.7.1). In case that this information is misleading this is another story.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! The patch solved my problem !